# Apache Storm - production mode executes outdated code

Tags: apache-storm

I'm having a very odd issue with Apache Storm: when I update my code and execute it in local mode everything works fine. However, the code that is executed when I run Storm in production mode is some previous version. This is absolutely mind-boggling. What do I need to wipe to force Storm to update the code that is run in production to the current version?

No, I am not imagining things. As I'm using default settings, the directory files are written to is of course dependent on whether Storm is run in local or in production mode. I then changed the name of the file I want to write, and, lo and behold, in production mode this code change is completely ignored and the old file name is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across the solution: I had to force Maven to do a full recompilation. For some reason it did not pick up the changes. It is still not clear to me why this happened because, after all, the source code is compiled prior to running the code locally as well.

So, run:

```
mvn clean install
mvn compile
```

Afterwards, the production topology runs the up-to-date code.